# Ftp support on windows phone 8.1

Tags: ftp, windows-phone-8.1

I have a class library that I created with the Windows Phone 8 SDK (it's the library given by Microsoft for adding ftp support). The problem is this library doesn't work on the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK, in fact the class: `system.windows.threading.dispatcher` can't be found. Do I have to create another library or is there any solution that could fix this?

Comment: Can you give more details about which library you're using, what type of Windows Phone 8.1 app are you building (WinRT, Silverlight?) etc.?

Comment: Your comment pointed me to my error. I was trying to add phone library to an universal project and the class Dispatcher which figure in my library can't be added in universal app (it belong to system.windows.threading.dispatcher which don't exist in universal app). Thanks for replying